# SonarQube parser error with virtual, noexcept destructor

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube has a rule (cpp:S3654) in which it wants destructors to be defined as noexcept.  However if I attempt to satisfy this rule with the following SonarQube reports a parser error:

virtual ~ConfigurationAccess() noexcept = default;

The gcc compiler is happy enough.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try to use the compliant solution as described [here](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules#rule_key=cpp%3AS3654)? Why are you using "virtual" and "= default"?

Comment: Jeroen, thanks for the feedback.  Even if I remove virtual and change it to ~ConfigurationAccess() noexcept { } I still get a parser error.  It seems to not like noexcept.